# Increasing the update rate of gst_element_query_position in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am busy creating a wrapper library (for node.js) around GStreamer. I have a working player, and I am using an interval to request the pipeline position (with percent formatting) every 200ms.

My issue however, is that I only receive an updated value every 1000ms.

I am calling `gst_element_query_position` (And have also tried attaching to the pad with `gst_pad_query_position` with the same result).

Is there any way to increase the update rate of the value retrieved by gst_element_query_position in order to present more granular time information?

Comment: Are you using GST_FORMAT_TIME or GST_FORMAT_PERCENT?  The docs indicate GST_FORMAT_PERCENT isn't well-implemented across elements.  http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstFormat.html#GstFormat

Comment: @mpr Thanks! I didn't see that comment in the docs. If you put that as an answer I will be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `gst_element_query_position`, use `GST_FORMAT_TIME` over `GST_FORMAT_PERCENT`.  GST_FORMAT_PERCENT is basically deprecated.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstFormat.html#GstFormat

We use the position in combination with the duration (from `gst_element_query_duration`) and it seems to work fine for more granular usage.